# The class of $a$ in $R/(b)$ is prime if and only if the class of $b$ in $R/(a)$ is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For $a,b$ in a commutative ring $R$, the class of $a$ in $R/(b)$ is prime
if and only if the class of $b$ in $R/(a)$ is prime.
It seems true but when I went to prove it I got stuck, though it's seemingly just a verification. Could you help me？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true. If $I$ and $J$ are ideals, then $(R/I) / (J/I) \cong R/(I+J) \cong (R/J) / (I/J)$ where I am writing $I/J$ for the image of $I$ in $R/J$ and $J/I$ for the image of $J$ in $R/I$ (these images are ideals because quotient maps are surjective). So $I/J$ is prime in $R/J$ if and only if $I+J$ is prime in $R$ if and only if $J/I$ is prime in $R/I$. And in particular, when $I=(a)$ and $J=(b)$, $a$ is prime in $R/(b)$ if and only if $b$ is prime in $R/(a)$ (if and only if the ideal $(a,b)$ is prime in $R$). Technically you need to be a little more careful, since if $b$ is prime and $a$ is divisible by $b$, then $a$ will be 0 in $R/(b)$, and hence not exactly prime, but that's more of a technicality. The statement about ideals remains true no matter what.

A note on notation: By $I/J$, I mean the image of $I$ in $R/J$. I feel the need to clarify since this is perhaps a little nonstandard.

Comment: sorry.I just reveiwing this anwser but I got stuck.Now I cant understand why the image of $I$ in $R/J$ is an ideal?

Comment: One way to see that is the correspondence theorem. Alternatively, the image of an ideal under a ring homomorphism is an ideal of the image subring, and quotient maps are surjective.

Comment: oh..the correspondence thm that I know states that there is a 1-1 correspondence between ideals containing $J$ and the ideals of quotient...so is it not necessary to have the condition about containing?

Comment: Well, the 1-1 correspondence part requires it to contain $J$, but often times the statement also includes that the image of an ideal under a quotient map is an ideal. However, the other argument I gave doesn't depend on anything else. The image of an ideal under a ring homomorphism is an ideal of the image subring. Since quotients are surjective, the image subring is the entire codomain, hence the image of an ideal is an ideal of the codomain.

Comment: your statement on $(R/I) / (J/I) \cong R/(I+J) \cong (R/J) / (I/J)$ is wrong unless $I=J$

Comment: @Daianne'deSouza It's correct if you interpret $I/J$ as the image of $I$ in $R/J$ (and similarly for $J/I$. Otherwise, if you interpret it as being a quotient, it doesn't make sense unless $I=J$, as you said. So perhaps I should have been a bit more clear about my notation. I'll edit in a note.

Comment: Wait, I already had a note on my notation at the end. Well I added another note nearer to the statement, since it was apparently confusing.